# Rounding building faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am very new to blender and have started making a building (image below). It is made of an extruded bezier curve converted to a mesh. However, I would like to round some edges (marked in red below) and don't know how to approach it. I have tried proportional editing, different modifiers, but nothing is working. I have included a picture of how I'd like it to look when seen from above. How could I do it?

[image: Building]
[image: Image2]
Any help is appreciated
Marius

Comment: Could you sketch out the edgeflow you are expecting on your mesh? From there we'll be able to suggest a tool, bu you should decide the kind of approach to topology based on your project needs. From the point you are presenting, I would probably give a try to booleans, but I can't tell if it's appropriate...one more thing: why you tagged cycles?

Comment: You may need to add more geometry... hard to tell. If you edit a screen grab of your existing geometry it would help. You could also edit into you question your .blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, I think it would be easier to make the shape you sketched first and then raise the height of the building using proportional Editing.